# Marshmallow- How to listen to music volume changes in a service?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-audiomanager

I have tried these ways to listen to volume changes in marshmallow :-

1. Undocumented intent action "android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION" , it works fine in many phones but does not work in some phones.
2. I have tried ContentObserver class to listen to volume change in Marshmallow but it does not work, it works fine in Lollipop.

Is there any other way to listen to music volume changes in marshmallow?
please help.